# Error while access alias in multilevel subquery MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

This is my query

```
SELECT *
FROM personal_store_application a, personal_store_application_lang b, (

  SELECT SUM( total ) total
  FROM (

     SELECT COUNT( NPID ) total
     FROM actnews
     WHERE `NPID` = a.PID
     UNION ALL SELECT COUNT( NPID ) total
     FROM logistics
     WHERE `NPID` = a.PID
  ) AS s
) AS x
WHERE a.Sn = b.Sn
AND b.Lang = 'zh-tw'
AND Application != 'S'
ORDER BY a.C_TIME DESC
```

This query breaks in the second level `Unknown column 'a.PID' in 'where clause'`
I cannot access alias a in the second level subquery. How to achieve this? The query works fine if I change `a.PID` to a static PID.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This JOIN style was effective deprecated in 1992. Join the 21st century

Comment: Then see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

when you are executing a subquery innermost query executes first, in your case `SELECT COUNT( NPID ) total
     FROM actnews
     WHERE NPID = a.PID
     UNION ALL SELECT COUNT( NPID ) total
     FROM logistics
     WHERE NPID = a.PID`

which does not know what is `a.` as it is declared in outer query hence the error.

Comment: I dont think so thats the case because if use `a.pid` in my first level subquery, its fine, it knows what is `a.PID`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use left join

```
 SELECT COUNT( NPID ) total
 FROM actnews
 LEFT JOIN personal_store_application ON `NPID` = personal_store_application.PID
```

Comment: Thanks @Jiang for the answer. No error but its getting the first record PID from `personal_store_application.PID` and thus all rows have same total.

Comment: It is because the temporary table name scope,you can go to Google for a better solution  "with"

Comment: do one thing add these two tables `personal_store_application a, personal_store_application_lang b` in `SELECT COUNT( NPID ) total
     FROM actnews
     WHERE NPID = a.PID
     UNION ALL SELECT COUNT( NPID ) total
     FROM logistics
     WHERE NPID = a.PID` for sure it should work then